# Adding progress bar to replicate function in R

Tags: r, progress-bar, replicate

I am using `replicate` to run my own `analyse` function multiple times (`analyse` returns a list):

```
results <- replicate(reps, analyse())
```

Is there a way to add progress bar, showing the percentage of replications finished at the moment? I have tried with `txtProgressBar`, but don't know how to make it work without a for-loop.

EDIT: reproducible example of `replicate:`

```
analyse <- function() {
  out <- list('a' = vector('list', 5), 'b' = vector('list', 5))
}
results <- replicate(3, analyse())
```

In my case, output of `analyse` is a deep list of lists with results. I would like the progress bar to update every time a new column of `results` is filled in, so after each replication.

Comment: you could add some sort of indicator in `analyse` function along with `Sys.sleep(1)` to explicitly print progress

Comment: That is one solution, but I would rather have in the form of a progress bar if possible

Comment: further we can use the `indicator` i mentioned as global variable and access it using `txtProgressBar` or other progress indicator at some time intervals

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to use `pbreplicate()` function from `pbapply` package. This package also contains respective progress bar functions for `apply()`, `lapply()` and `sapply()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following example in a `for` loop

```
x  <- seq(1,100)
pb   <- txtProgressBar(1, 100, style=3)
StartTime <- Sys.time()
for(i in x){
   Sys.sleep(0.01)
   setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
}

Sys.time() - StartTime
```

Comment: How can I apply this example to `replicate` function? As I have mentioned in my question, I do know how to do it in a for-loop. However, I want to use `replicate`, becauese loops are to slow for my data.

Comment: I did not notice the changes. Can you post a reproducible `replicate` example?